# Fastest way to execute system call and get string response in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, system

For an application I need to perform a system call and read the output a few times. What's the fastest way to execute a system command from Python and read the output as a string?

Here's a demo code:

```
import time
import os
import subprocess

cmd = 'ipconfig'

#Takes 4.85 seconds
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(0, 100):
    os.popen(cmd).read()
dt = time.time()-t0
print(dt)

#Takes 3 seconds
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(0, 100):
    subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
dt = time.time()-t0
print(dt)
```

The first call takes around 4.85 seconds in my computer while the second 3. There are also other ways creating processes, etc. that perhaps are even faster. Which is the fastest way you can come with to execute a system call and get the output as a string?

Comment: `There are also other ways creating processes, etc. that perhaps are even faster.` ... You should test/time them and report back.

Comment: You might want to use the [`timeit` module`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) for your tests.